# Hiding the Cursor

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, directx, mouse

I have a windows program with directx/opengl renderers, and a custom mouse rendered as a quad. The program currently runs windowed.

The problem is the standard windows mouse is overlaid ontop of my custom cursor. How do I hide it when its inside my window?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `ShowCursor(FALSE);` when you  init your window.